# Connectivity with DB for Window store using Blank app template

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am trying to make a quiz application for Windows Store using the blank app template (in VS2013). I have the UI laid out in XAML but I don't know how to fetch Questions saved in my DB (MS access or SQL).

I have tried to find tutorials related to it,but what I have found is for WPF and Windows Forms. I had chosen the Blank app template, so can anyone explain how to fetch question from the Database in an application using Blank app template?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there's a good reason you couldn't find a tutorial for accessing a local DB in the WinRT environment. **You can't**. Microsoft didn't even include the requistite ADO.NET assemblies, assuming you could get out of the sandbox in order to connect.

There *is* a SQLLite project for Windows Store apps, found [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/02/27/build-a-windows-store-app-using-sqlite.aspx). That's about as good as you can get it right now in terms of a local relational database in a windows store app.

What Microsoft *intended* for you to do was to store your database in the cloud (and if they have their way, on Microsoft Azure) and access it using a web service. Support for that is all over the WinRT API. It sounds like thats probably what you want anyways (unless you expect your users to generate their own questions) so I would go into that route.

A starting point for that would be to use [Azure Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/).

One last thing to note, WPF and WinForms are not WinRT, but there *are* other project templates (like the Hub template) that are. The fact that you chose the "Blank" template doesn't really affect anything in this regard.

Comment: thanks sir for your reply & could please tell me  what type of template this app QUIZ MANIA  [link](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-in/app/quiz-mania/bcc7a8e6-f9ae-4a5b-a61c-fd563adc014a)  had used.I have to create a app similar to it .SO to build this type of app what i should study and rest important knowledge required to build it

Comment: @PrateekKapoor That looks like a standard windows store app, the initial template doesn't really matter as I mentioned earlier. Judging by the screenshots, It is getting its data from a web service that provides the questions. If I had any advice, learn about RESTful web services (especially with Microsoft Azure). Honestly, the whole project requires some understanding of architecture you may or may not have yet, so tread carefully and consider doing something a bit simpler.

Comment: @PrateekKapoor Ok, then they stored there data serialized in a file or using the SQLLite project I mentioned. Again, pick your method and do some research. If you have a *specific* question about it, then ask a new SO question.

Comment: sorry for asking silly question i have to complete my assignment as early as possible thats why in a bit of hurry.just help me out in 1 thing weather a similar  kind of app cab be made in WPF

Comment: @PrateekKapoor Yes, you could easily make it in WPF. Obviously it wouldn't have the exact look and feel of a Windows 8 app, but you can access local RDBMSs

Comment: sir if i want to access my qn in the text box from Ms access DB ..but unable to do could you please help me out

Comment: @PrateekKapoor Thats not nearly enough information to go on. Post a new SO question (with a *ton* more details) and link to it here if you'd like me to look at it. Also, access *sucks*. Consider using a real DBMS like SQL server (even SQL server express!)